# Unable to create azure.createQueueService() in Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I want to go through the queue data in Azure queue storage in a HTTP trigger function App.
I add the "äzure-storage" Node.js package and using following code:
`var azure = require('azure-storage');`
But either the code `var queueSvc = azure.createQueueService();` or `var queueSvc = azure.createQueueService(<storage connection string>);` is failure when execute the function. I got below exception

> "reason": "PassThrough",
>   "exception": {
>   "ClassName": "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException",
>   "Message": "A task was canceled.",
>   "Data": null,
>   "InnerException": null,
>   "HelpURL": null,
>   "StackTraceString": " at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at AzureFunctions.Code.PassThroughRequestManager.d__2.MoveNext()",
>   "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
>   "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
>   "ExceptionMethod": "8\nThrowForNonSuccess\nmscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter\nVoid ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)",
>   "HResult": -2146233029,
>   "Source": "mscorlib",
>   "WatsonBuckets": null
>   }
>   }

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this issue in a simple HTTP trigger function with Javascript:

- Install [azure-storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) via Kudu debug console (`https://<functionname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`):

  [image]
- In the `index.js` file I have this:

  [image]

Comment: Yes, works for me now while refer to u sample. I called the code "azure.createQueueService" within a HTTP Request call function before, and so the issue may related to the long timing  call...